# How to store class pointer in a Vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class that stores some symbols.

```
class SymbolInfo{   
public:
    string name;
    string type;
    string token;
    int num;
    char ch;
    float fl;   
    int arrSize;
    int array_index_holder;
    SymbolInfo *next;
    Function *func;
    SymbolInfo* myarray;
    SymbolInfo(){
        name="";
        type="";
        token="";
        next = NULL;
        arrSize = -1;
        array_index_holder = -1;

    }

    SymbolInfo(string name, string type){
        this->name = name;
        this->type = type;
        token="";
        next = NULL;
        arrSize = -1;
        array_index_holder = -1;


    }

    string getname(){
        return name;
    }

    void setname(string name){
        name = name;
    }

    string gettype(){
        return type;
    }

    void settype(string type){
        type = type;
    }




};
```

I wanted to make an array of symbols. So I use this class in a `Vector` and created this:

```
Vector<SymbolInfo*>array;
```

And with the integer size, I was trying to create an array like this:

```
SymbolInfo *s= table->LookUp($3->name);
$3->type = dataType;
    table->Insert($3->name, $3->type);
    s = table->LookUp($3->name);
    s->token = "ARRAY";
    int size = $5->num;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            array[i].push_back(*s);
    }
```

$3 and $5 are SymbolInfo type pointer(it's for YACC/BISON)
After executing this I got this error:

```
parser.y: In function ‘int yyparse()’:
parser.y:200:12: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘array.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<SymbolInfo*, std::allocator<SymbolInfo*> >(((std::vector<SymbolInfo*>::size_type)i))’, which is of pointer type ‘SymbolInfo*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
   array[i].push_back(*s);
            ^
```

What am I doing wrong? How to resolve this problem?

Comment: From the definition `Vector<SymbolInfo*>array;` `array[i]` is a pointer to class `SymbolInfo`

Comment: In C++, `Vector` != `vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer is just called `s`, and the vector is just called `array`.

So:

```
array.push_back(s);
```

The expression `array[i]` gives you one of the pointers already in the vector, and the expression `*s` gives you whatever `s` points to (it is a *dereference* operation).

Comment: The error clearly states that `->` must be used instead of `.`

Comment: @vordhosbn: No, it doesn't. It says "maybe you meant to use". In this case, we didn't.

Comment: Isn't `array[i]` a pointer? At least I am assuming from the declaration `Vector<SymbolInfo*>array;`...

Comment: It's for matching a string int c[2]. So when I find string "c[2]", I was trying to create  a vector of size 2, each containing the SymbolInfo class.

Comment: @vordhosbn: Yes, a pointer to a `SymbolInfo`, not a pointer to a vector. Which is why I pointed out the OP should have written just `array` instead.

Comment: @Rrakib: I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

If array is a vector than just call push_back on it. It will put the element at the back of the vector. If you use the [] operator it evaluates to reference to the item in the vector in this case a pointer to some Symbol table info. If you want to store something in the vector at index i given the vector has an index i then use the line of code

```
vector[i] = something;
```

Comment: It's for matching a string int c[2]. So when I find string "c[2]", I was trying to create a vector of size 2, each containing the SymbolInfo class

Comment: I'm assuming this is some AST thing. If you want a Vector of size two with the exact same reference in it you should just use the exact line of code @BoundaryImposition supplied and use the default constructor for vector. If you call push_back on a vector it will grow the size of the vector by 1 and append it on the back.